# Natural webservice type for Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, mobile

We want to track `GPS` data on Android and send it to server, there will be also another two-way communication.

Question: What is the most natural/easy-to-implement type of webservice on the server side to which can Android connect? We would like to use classic .NET WCF Web services, is it a good choice or something like XML-RPC would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest to implement would be REST Based API that returns JSON data (whichever platform you choose).

Part of the reasons :

- Built in HttpClient in Android for REST Operation such as GET AND POST.
- Easier to construct the input through URL for GET or even POST compared to SOAP or XML message construction
- JSON library is built in as part of Android, making it easy to work with JSON result. Walking JSON key-value pair is easier than walking through XML Structure
- As a mobile app, it needs a compact data to be transferred through a network and JSON is lighter than  XML RPC
- As an additional plus outside Android, the REST API with JSON is also easier to integrate with the web counterpart, so you will have API for multi channels delivery

Comment: How easy would it be to implement the server side service using .NET/C#?

Comment: In theory (and I am not .NET expert), the service would be returning string object to the outputstream. We then use a JSON library to generate the JSON String representation from your object or construct JSON String manually.

Comment: Great -- and can it be used with the "push" ability? We want to send data to the phone asynchronously.

Comment: Looks like there is a built in support already for WCF for JSON. See the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb472488.aspx. It seems you could set the data format via ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json

Comment: A lot people have suggested using the UrbanAirship or XTify service for push notification so that you have the ability to support multiple platforms if you decide to. Both UrbanAirship and XTify provide the API so that you could send push notification to multiple platforms. They hide the actual implementation from us (e.g. C2DM for Android or APN for iOS) so we are only dealing with the Push Notification API